# Text editor doen't display content after updating Meteor to 0.8.0

Tags: javascript, meteor

I recently integrated [Simditor](https://github.com/mycolorway/simditor) to [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/):

**post_submit.html:**

```
Template.postSubmit.rendered = function() {
  $(function() {
    var editor;
    editor = new Simditor({
      textarea: $("#input-content"),
      placeholder: "Just write",
      pasteImage: true,
      toolbar: ["title", "bold", "italic", "underline"],
      upload: {
        url: "/upload"
      }
    });
  });
};
```

**post_submit.js:**

```
<template name="postSubmit">
  <form class="form" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea name="content" class="form-control" id="input-content" rows="3">{{content}}</textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

**post_page.js:**

```
  <div class="mainbar col-md-12">
    {{> postSubmit}}
  </div>
</template>
```

**EDIT**

```
this.route("postPage", {
  path: "/posts/:_id",
  data: function() {
    return Posts.findOne(this.params._id);
  }
});
```

And it used to work perfectly, but after updating Meteor to 0.8.0 the content suddenly disappeared from both the contenteditable div (generated by Simditor) and the textarea (which had the same content as the former one):

[image]

What could be the problem? I think it has to do with the way the new `rendered` method works.

Comment: it surely does have something to do with the new rendering engine. The way you would use jquery plugins might be different. Please be sure to read http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Blaze_Notes and https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze

Comment: @imslavko Thanks but it seems like my `rendered` and `jQuery` code is identical as the one shown in that page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because you are using `{{content}}` inside a subtemplate. From 0.8.0 you can no longer access parent template's helpers. You can however, access the parent template's data.

This may not work, but it may be the problem you are having. Its hard to tell given the information you've provided its not easy to reproduce.

One way to get this to work is to either extend your data context to include `content`, or to manually send it through.

HTML

```
<template name="parentTemplate">

    {{#with contentData}}
        {{> postSubmit}}
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.parentTemplate.helpers({

     //Not sure about this part
     contentData: function() {
        return {
            content: Template.parentTemplate.content()
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: I refractored the code so that the form is part of the postPage template instead of a child. Same problem. I think the new render-only-once-model is causing the content to disappear from the textarea/contenteditable div for some reason. It does display if I put the content somewhere else.

Comment: I think I understand the issue a bit more. Try waiting for the subscription to complete before the page is rendered or using a Deps.autorun() to re-run `Template.postSubmit.rendered` (or the new postPage one) to re-init SimEditor when the data changes. So it would be just like before

Comment: Thanks could you give me an example of using `Deps.autorun()` on `Template.postSubmit.rendered`?

Comment: I tried putting it right under `Template.postSubmit.rendered = function() {` but didn't work.

Comment: It is not like that, you have to call the code you had in the .rendered function() or the stuff inside it with the Deps.autorun. I can assist a bit more but I need you to post some code up of the reactive portion of your query/how you get data from your js to your template, since `Deps.autorun` requires this to recognize when to re-run.

Comment: You meant my routes? (see EDIT).